# Is there any angular select module support multi layer?

Tags: angularjs, multi-select, ui-select

I'm looking for an angular select module which supports multi-select with tree structure. Well-known ui-select doesn't seem to have such a feature. I found a module called [angular-multi-select-tree](https://github.com/a5hik/angular-multi-select-tree), but the user interface is poor.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can customize the UI with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, Mattia. That's an option too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.jstree.com/ plus the angular directive that wraps this https://github.com/arvindr21/jsTree-directive

Comment: Hi Rave, it doesn't seem to have multi-select feature. But still an awesome tool.